# How to write the JPQL equavalent of db.Person.find({_id:{pid:'1',email:'test@gamil.com'}})

Tags: java, hibernate-ogm

***How to convert the mongo db query into JPQL query***
I have tried the followings but its returning empty list.

```
Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.pid =:pid AND p.email =:email");
query.setParameter("pid", 1);
query.setParameter("email", "test@gmail.com");
List recs = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: This look good. Would you try **SELECT p FROM Person p** only(without parameter) and verify result if that contains result

Comment: Yes, it contains the result

Comment: Please try to use Ordinal Parameters it means SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.pid =?1 AND p.email =?2". query.setParameter("1, 1001);
query.setParameter(2, "test@gmail.com");

Comment: i have already tried the above suggestion

Comment: How does the `Person` entity look like? Does it have an attribute `pid`, or is it the name of the database column?

Comment: In that case, Please update your question with possible ways you have tried, as well as response after **Select p from Person p**. I don't see any issue they way you defining query. Try to hardcode string in query and try once, If that does give you response.